# How to make Chrome user proxy server on ArchLinux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, proxy, arch-linux

I would like to set HTTP proxy for Google Chrome on ArchLinux.

When I open the proxy settings section in Chrome GUI I get:

> When running Google Chrome under a supported desktop environment, the
>   system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not
>   supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration.
>
> But you can still configure via the command line. Please see man
>   google-chrome for more information on flags and environment variables.

Running it with `google-chrome-stable --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8080`  has no effect.

Going to `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` reveals:

> Effective proxy settings
>
> Use DIRECT connections. Source: GSETTINGS Original proxy settings
>
> Auto-detect Source: GSETTINGS

So I use `gsettings` to set those values.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled
true
gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy.http host
localhost
gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy.http port
8080
```

But still not success - `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` ouput stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

For google-chrome-stable in Manjaro Linux , even when setting the proxy in the Network it was not detecting; But when you run it as

> /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --http-proxy=xxxx.net:8080
>   --https-proxy=xxxxx.net:8080 %U

it works